# Return value of Webklex\PHPIMAP\Connection\Protocols\ImapProtocol::moveMessage() must be of the type boolean, array returned

Tags: laravel, imap

When connecting to 365 via OAUTH we attempt to move a message to a folder and receive the error

`Return value of Webklex\PHPIMAP\Connection\Protocols\ImapProtocol::moveMessage() must be of the type boolean, array returned`

Connection settings:

```php
$Token = $this->GetLoginToken();
            $cm = new ClientManager;

            $this->info("IMAP Connecting.");
            $this->oClient = $cm->make([
                'host' => 'outlook.office365.com',
                'port' => 993,
                'encryption' => 'ssl',
                'validate_cert' => true,
                'username' => *removed*, 
                'password' =>  $Token,
                'protocol' => 'imap',
                'authentication' => "oauth"
            ]);
```

Line producing the error

```php
$Msg->move('Processed', true);
```

This should just move the message, but as it is complaining about the return type not being a boolean I've no idea where to start!  Using version 4.0

Comment: This is a bug in the package `Webklex\PHPIMAP` and they have to fix this. I see you have created an issue on the Github page.

Comment: It looks like this is fixed in the newer version

Comment: @GertB. thanks for that, please post as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the package `Webklex\PHPIMAP` in version 4.0.
(returns an array instead of the bool return type)

This is a problem that should be fixed by the package developer.

In the newer version of the package this issue is fixed. So an update is needed.